# How to design notification system when using hybrid databases

Tags: sql-server, database-design, neo4j, notifications

I am using hybrid database (graph DB and RDBMS) for the social website I am developing. I store "connected" data such as friendship relationship between users in the graph database and I store less connected data such as user authentication information, notification data in the RDMS (SQL Server). Now, when two users become friends, I store their relationship in a neo4j database and need to notify the users. The first task is very trivial and for the second task I'm thinking of creating an `TransactionEventHandler` that would fire when a new `:FRIENDS` relationship is created (see this [link](https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/03/25/triggers-in-neo4j/)).

However, since I'm using the **Notification** table in the RDMS to store the notifications, I'm bit confused what to do  after the *relationship created* event fires. I have two possible options on my mind:

1. Move the notification all over to the graph database and create a notification node and `:NOTIFIED` relationship between the user and the notification nodes. But in this case, what I can't figure out is how to notify the application of the newly created nodes.
2. Access the SQL Server database using jdbc and insert a notification in the Notification table when an event fires. And user `SqlDependency` to notify the application of changes in the Notification table.

So, which option is appropriate in terms of performance and scalability? Or is there a better alternative?

If it matters, I am using ASP.NET MVC for the server side programming.

Comment: There's simply no right answer to this - just opinions. When dealing with polyglot persistence (multiple databases), you'll need to figure out the best solution that works for your app. *Note: What you have is not a hybrid database - it's just two databases, hence the term polyglot persistence.*